# php file_get_contents without filename

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to do a file_get_contents from a site without a filename:

```
<?php
$datalink = 'https://www.gymtranet.dk/discipliner/idraetsgymnastik/deltagere/downloadkigindv/?Num=1801';
$data = file_get_contents($datalink);
echo $data;
?>
```

But I don't get any data. All I get is a blank page.

Any ideas why?

*I am not the owner of the site I am downloading from, but I am allowed to do it.*

Comment: What error you see? I am able to get data using same code.

Comment: Check if [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled. Also check if openssl is installed and enabled.

Comment: it should absolutely work fine